# Basic harmonic series (not sure)

Tags: sequences-and-series

The series I am presented with:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n+17}{6n^3+4n^2+5}$$
How can I find the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n$ of the form $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n=c\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}$ where $c\gt0$ such that $b_n\ge\frac{n+17}{6n^3+4n^2+5}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$?
[Side note: I'm not entirely sure if this is in the Harmonic Series subject]

Comment: This is not the harmonic series: the harmonic series is $\sum \frac{1}{n}$. For your example, show that $\frac{\frac{n+17}{6n^3 + 4n^2 +5}}{\frac{1}{n²}}$ is bounded and you can now conclude.

Comment: hint: For $n>17$ then $n+17< ?$ and $4n^2+5>0$. So $c=\frac 13$ works.

Answer (score 0):

Simplifying the following inequality
$$\begin{align}
&\qquad \ \  \ \ \frac{n+17}{6n^3+4n^2+5} \le \frac{c}{n^2} \\
&\iff n^3+17n^2 \le 6cn^3+4cn^2+5c \\
&\iff(6c-1)n^3 + (4c-17)n^2 + 5c \ge 0
\end{align}$$
Taking $4c > 17$ or $c > 5$ is enough.

---

You can see how it works with $c = 6$:

[image]